# Unable to start mysql from official docker image: No space left on device

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-8.0

I just pulled the official `mysql` image, more precisely: `mysql:8.0.32`.

Using the following command throws an error:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true -d mysql:8.0.32


2023-01-26T10:46:07.380836Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.

2023-01-26T10:46:07.380926Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) initializing of server in progress as process 81

mysqld: Error writing file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)

2023-01-26T10:46:07.386811Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010076] [Server] Initialization of the server's UUID failed because it could not be read from the auto.cnf file. If this is a new server, the initialization failed because it was not possible to generate a new UUID.

2023-01-26T10:46:07.386835Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

2023-01-26T10:46:07.386840Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2023-01-26T10:46:07.387240Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

2023-01-26 10:46:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.

2023-01-26 10:46:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2023-01-26 10:46:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.

2023-01-26 10:46:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
```

As you can see, the first error indicates a file could not be written:

```
mysqld: Error writing file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)
```

However, there is nothing mentionning any prerequisite in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

How am I supposed to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried moving/deleting some files to make some disk space?

Comment: @SimonGoater I have more than 39Gb disk space left on my laptop.

Comment: For some reason, restarting docker made the error disapear...

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after mounting a volume to `/var/lib/mysql`.